# org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject ANDROID

Tags: android

I am creating a app in Android and trying to read Json value from the service I created in C# using MVC. The service is returning the follwing Json response.

```
[{"empID":"1","Fname":"Khayyam","SurName":"Studenti","DOB":null,"gender":null},{"empID":"2","Fname":"Student 2","SurName":"Zaheer","DOB":null,"gender":null}]
```

The following section of program is fetching the value from web service and storing in string.

```
_input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_urlConnection.getInputStream()));

String _data;
StringBuilder _Sb = new StringBuilder();

while((_data = _input.readLine() )!=null){
    _Sb.append(_data);
    _Sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}

_RestfulString= _Sb.toString();
```

.....

and in the postExecution of AsyncTask

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused){
    JSONObject _response;
    try{
        _response = new JSONObject(_RestfulString);
        JSONArray  _jsonNodes = _response.optJSONArray("rest");

        for(int x=0; x< _RestfulString.length();x++){
            JSONObject _childNode = _jsonNodes.getJSONObject(x);
            Log.d("Fname",_childNode.optString("Fname"));
            txtFname.setText(_childNode.optString("Fname"));
            txtSname.setText(_childNode.optString("SurName"));
            txtDOB.setText(_childNode.optString("DOB"));
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception exp) {
        Log.d("Excetpion",exp.getMessage());
        _pDialog.hide();
    }
}
```

As soon as the program hits

```
_response = new JSONObject(_RestfulString);
```

it raise exception of

```
Value [{"empID":"1","Fname":"Muhammad Khayyam","SurName":"Qureshii","DOB":null,"gender":null},{"empID":"2","Fname":"Sobia","SurName":"Zaheer","DOB":null,"gender":null}]

of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Answer (score 3):

It is clearly visible that the input is in `JSONArray` and you are attempting to convert it into `JSONObject` and your desired `JSONObject` is perhaps at `0`th index of it. Try below code

```
JSONArray arr=new JSONArray(_RestfulString);
_response=arr.getJSONObject(0);
```